# How to change project SDK to use java 8?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I just updated my scala plugin and it may have messed up my intellij settings I am not sure.

My import project page looks like this:

[image]

I get this error when trying to open the sbt project:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Change the java version in the Project SDK combo box to java 8

Comment: Try File > Project Structure > SDKs . If your Java 8 SDK does not exist, you can click + and add JDK from there.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project Structure:

[image]

Under the "Project Settings" select "Project". Check if you have Java 8 installed:

[image]

If so, select it and press OK. Otherwise, [download Java](https://java.com/en/download/), and the press "New" and select the new Java version:

[image]

And then press OK.